# Lando local dev site tabs link to live

Tags: 9

Suddenly, my local dev site's tabs have started linking to the live site. For example, when I view https://mysite.lndo.site and click the edit tab, it points to https://mysite.com/node/166. If I type in https://mysite.lndo.site/node/166, it still redirects me to the live site. This is a recent phenomenon, but I can't work out what change has caused this to start happening. Is there a simple setting I'm missing somewhere?

Drupal 9.4.1
PHP 8.0.18

Comment: Did you pull the database from the live site recently?

Comment: Yes. But I've done that before as well.

Comment: And also, I just pulled the live db down to my test env (at Pantheon) and it is not having the same issue.

Comment: Sounds like you've got a rewrite rule based on an environment variable or some such

Answer (score 3):

@Clive's comment was on track. I'm using the Domain modules and under Domain Source Settings, it was not set to disable link rewrites for these routes. This site is 2 years old now and I don't recall ever setting these before though, so something must have changed that I haven't caught onto yet. Anyway, leaving this here with what I figured out for posterity's sake.